# CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null)

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, xcode6

I got this error every time that I install the app on `Simulator` using `Xcode 6`

```
2014-09-27 11:25:01.286 MyFace[2992:1780149] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/douglasferreira/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DAC1BEDE-8673-471C-ADFD-923654C78719/data/Containers/Data/Application/D2213EE4-3807-44FF-9FD0-E7C6C1BD18A2/Library/MyFace.sqlite options:{
NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t    be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x7fe566317030 {reason=File appeared during sanity check; this seems suspicious} with userInfo dictionary {
reason = "File appeared during sanity check; this seems suspicious";
}

[2014-09-27 11:25:01:288] [ERROR] Problems to initialize persistent store coordinator: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x7fe566317030 {reason=File appeared during sanity check; this seems suspicious}, The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)
```

This is how I create `NSManagedObjectModel` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (!_managedObjectModel)
    {
        // It is created from the application's model with the following name and extension
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyFace" withExtension:@"momd"];
        _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    }
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (!_persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        // generic variable to hold any error occurred during context creation
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSDictionary *persistentOptions = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES};

        // Create the coordinator with the previous parameters
        NSURL *storeURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFace.sqlite"];

        // try to initialize persistent store coordinator with options defined below
        self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
        [self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                      configuration:nil
                                                                URL:storeURL
                                                            options:persistentOptions
                                                              error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] Problems to initialize persistent store coordinator: %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I've tried every kind of flags.. but I don't know how to get over it.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it's a path problem.  Do you get the same thing if you use `NSDocumentDirectory` instead of `NSLibraryDirectory`?

Comment: I got a different error.. I think it's worse. `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x7fbec9c36e70 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}, The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
I had two threads accessing the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` while it's was not created yet. So I added a `@synchronize` on the lazy init and queued the requests.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in Swift 4, Thanks to @Douglas for the solution

What i did was adding `objc_sync_enter` and `objc_sync_exit` between the `persistentStoreCoordinator`.

Example:

```
 lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {

        objc_sync_enter(self)

        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
            let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("moduleName.sqlite")
            var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
            do {
                try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]) // maybe change after pre - production
            } catch {
                // Report any error we got.
                var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
                dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject
                dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject
                dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
                let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

                #if DEBUG
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
                #endif
                abort()
            }

        objc_sync_exit(self)

        return coordinator
    }()
```

Comment: The lock works perfectly for me. My problem were parallelized Unit Tests.

Answer (score 1):

Douglas is right. For the iOS noobies like me, the wording would be the following:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    @synchronized(self) {

        if (!_persistentStoreCoordinator)
        {
            // generic variable to hold any error occurred during context creation
            NSError *error = nil;

            NSDictionary *persistentOptions = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES};

            // Create the coordinator with the previous parameters
            NSURL *storeURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
            storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFace.sqlite"];

            // try to initialize persistent store coordinator with options defined below
            self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
            [self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                          configuration:nil
                                                                    URL:storeURL
                                                                options:persistentOptions
                                                                  error:&error];

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"[ERROR] Problems to initialize persistent store coordinator: %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }

    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```